# Segmentation fault: 11 - 4D Numerical Integration Error (C++)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, numeric, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I have written three dimensional integration code which calls a gaussian quadrature routine to do the integration as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float qgaus(float (*func)(float), float a, float b)
{
    int j;
    float xr,xm,dx,s;
    static float x[]={0.0,0.1488743389,0.4333953941,
        0.6794095682,0.8650633666,0.9739065285}; 
    static float w[]={0.0,0.2955242247,0.2692667193, 
        0.2190863625,0.1494513491,0.0666713443};

    xm = 0.5*(b+a); 
    xr = 0.5*(b-a);
    s = 0;

    for (j=1;j<=5;j++) 
    {
        dx=xr*x[j];
        s += w[j]*((*func)(xm+dx)+(*func)(xm-dx)); 
    }
    return s *= xr; 
}

float func(float x,float y,float z)
{
    float f = x*y*z;
    return f;
}

float yy1(float x)
{
    float y = x;
    return y;
}

float yy2(float x)
{
    float y = 2*x;
    return y;
}

float z1(float x,float y)
{
    float z = 5*x*y;
    return z;
}

float z2(float x,float y)
{
    float z = 10*x*x*y;
    return z;
}

static float xsav,ysav;
static float (*nrfunc)(float,float,float);

float quad3d(float (*func)(float, float, float), float x1, float x2)
{
    float qgaus(float (*func)(float), float a, float b); 
    float f1(float x);

    nrfunc=func;
    return qgaus(f1,x1,x2); 
}

float f1(float x) 
{
    float qgaus(float (*func)(float), float a, float b); 
    float f2(float y);
    float yy1(float),yy2(float);

    xsav=x;
    return qgaus(f2,yy1(x),yy2(x)); 
}

float f2(float y)  
{
    float qgaus(float (*func)(float), float a, float b); 
    float f3(float z);
    float z1(float,float),z2(float,float);

    ysav = y;
    return qgaus(f3,z1(xsav,y),z2(xsav,y)); 
}

float f3(float z)  
{
    return (*nrfunc)(xsav,ysav,z); 
}

int main ()
{
    float R;
    R = quad3d(func, 0, 1);
    cout << R << endl;
}
```

This code works perfectly for any three dimensional function I have tested it with. I have attempted to modify it to compute a four dimensional function by replacing the 3d routine with a 4d one:

```
static float wsav,xsav,ysav;
static float (*nrfunc)(float,float,float,float);

float quad4d(float (*func)(float, float, float, float), float w1, float w2)
{
    float qtrap(float (*func)(float), float a, float b); 
    float f1(float w);

    nrfunc=func;
    return qtrap(f1,w1,w2); 
}

float f1(float w) 
{
    float qtrap(float (*func)(float), float a, float b); 
    float f2(float x);
    float x1(float),x2(float);

    wsav = w;
    return qtrap(f2,x1(w),x2(w)); 
}

float f2(float x) 
{
    float qtrap(float (*func)(float), float a, float b); 
    float f3(float y);
    float yy1(float,float),yy2(float,float);

    xsav = x;
    return qtrap(f2,yy1(wsav,x),yy2(wsav,x)); 
}

float f3(float y)  
{
    float qtrap(float (*func)(float), float a, float b); 
    float f4(float z);
    float z1(float,float,float),z2(float,float,float);

    ysav = y;
    return qtrap(f3,z1(wsav,xsav,y),z2(wsav,xsav,y)); 
}

float f4(float z)  
{
    float t = (*nrfunc)(wsav,xsav,ysav,z); 
    return t;
}
```

This code compiles correctly, but will output "Segmentation fault: 11" when I run it. From what I understand, this implies that there is either some sort of problem with the arrays or a memory allocation error, but neither seem to make sense since there was no problem with the 3d case. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger to the program? You are almost certainly going beyond the bounds of an array somewhere, or inappropriately calculating the offset to an address, and making an unsafe/unbounded memory reference.

Comment: What is with all the function local function prototypes?

Comment: I'd also recommend ditching the vintage C habit of declaring uninitialized variables at the beginning and instead declaring them as late as possible (and giving them a value immediately). An uninitialized variable can often cause problems, and this style makes it harder to spot first usage.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).